# How to map ctrl-z to fg in fish

Tags: fish

I am trying to implement a feature from the following article:

[How to boost your vim productivity](http://sheerun.net/2014/03/21/how-to-boost-your-vim-productivity/)

in the **fish** shell. The Author in the Article uses the following code to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in **zsh** to the "fg" command.

```
fancy-ctrl-z () {
  if [[ $#BUFFER -eq 0 ]]; then
    BUFFER="fg"
    zle accept-line
  else
    zle push-input
    zle clear-screen
  fi
}
zle -N fancy-ctrl-z
bindkey '^Z' fancy-ctrl-z
```

The intention is to quickly switch between a vim instance in the foreground and the shell.

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> backgrounds vim, and switches to the shell, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> again should foreground vim again, so switching quickly is possible.

How would I replicate that in fish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fish currently doesn't let you catch `SIGTSTP`, which is what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends. You can however bind another key. For example, you could write:

```
bind \ck 'fg %'
```

This makes control-K switch back to the last backgrounded process.

It looks like the zsh `fancy-ctrl-z` function has a separate mode where it clears the screen if there's input on the command line. I'm not sure what that's about, but that can be replicated in fish if you want, something like:

```
bind \ck 'if test -z (commandline) ; fg %; else ; clear; commandline ""; end'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in fish [since version 3.2.0](https://fishshell.com/docs/3.2/relnotes.html#new-or-improved-bindings).

Here's an example of how to map this to `fg`:

```bash
bind \cz 'fg 2>/dev/null; commandline -f repaint'
```

> - `2>/dev/null` removes the `Send job X, “PROGRAM” to foreground` message, omit that if you wish to keep it.
> - `commandline -f repaint` tells fish to redraw the prompt to avoid weird cursor position issues.

Source: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7152#issuecomment-663575001

Answer (score 0):

If anyone want to do this in Bash, this should work:

```bash
# Add this somewhere in your ~/.bashrc

# Use bash-preexec.sh (https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec) to:
# - disable the Ctrl-Z keybinding before printing the prompt
# - enable the Ctrl-Z keybinding before executing a command
#
# This way, we are able to repurpose Ctrl-Z when in a Bash interactive
# prompt. But any command ran by Bash will still be able to suspend normally
# with Ctrl-Z.
#
# Note: You might need to change this path to your bash-preexec.sh location.
source ~/.config/bash/bash-preexec.sh
preexec () {
  stty susp '^Z'
}
precmd () {
  stty susp undef
}

# Bind Ctrl-Z to "fg %-" (resume next to last suspended job, or last if only one)
# This binding works like this:
# - If you have one job, Ctlr-Z will toggle in and out of it.
# - If you have more  jobs, "Ctrl-Z Ctrl-Z" will toggle between the last two.
bind '"\C-z":"fg %-\n"'
```